# What is the purpose of the property "encoding" in Schema.org?

Tags: seo, schema.org

I'm studying schemas for a future project and I find this [encoding](https://schema.org/encoding) property. The information about it leads to a cycle of repeated information and I still don't know the purpose of this one.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s say you write about a song on your blog, and you offer it for download as MP3 and OGG.

A [`MusicRecording`](http://schema.org/MusicRecording) item describes the song, with properties like [`byArtist`](http://schema.org/byArtist) (for the song’s artist) and [`about`](http://schema.org/about) (for the song’s topic). This data is about the song (i.e., the work), independent of the digital files that "encode" this song.

Such a digital file can be referenced with the [`encoding`](http://schema.org/encoding) property. It takes a [`MediaObject`](http://schema.org/MediaObject) item as value (in this example, we’d use the child type [`AudioObject`](http://schema.org/AudioObject)), with properties like [`encodingFormat`](http://schema.org/encodingFormat) (e.g., "OGG") and [`contentSize`](http://schema.org/contentSize) (e.g., "2.9 MB").

Example (in RDFa Lite):

```html
<article vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="MusicRecording">

  <h1 property="name">sad robot</h1>
  <div property="byArtist" typeof="MusicGroup"><span property="name">pornophonique</span></div>
  <link property="url" href="/sad-robot" />

  <div property="encoding" typeof="AudioObject">
    <div property="encodingFormat">OGG</div>
    <div property="contentSize">2.9 MB</div>
    <a property="contentUrl" href="/sad-robot.ogg">Download</a>
  </div>

  <div property="encoding" typeof="AudioObject">
    <div property="encodingFormat">MP3</div>
    <div property="contentSize">3.1 MB</div>
    <a property="contentUrl" href="/sad-robot.mp3">Download</a>
  </div>

</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Schema is suppose to describe the information and not the transport format.

Encoding is the process of converting data into a format required for a number of information processing needs.

So, encoding encapsulates data.